# Number of days between each date in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column of date in an Oracle table

```
date_column
-----------
12/02/2016
05/02/2016
25/01/2016
08/01/2016
18/12/2015
...
```

I would like to know if there is a method to calculate in an other column the number of days every couple of successive dates. For example the number of days between `12/02/2016` and `05/02/2016`, the number of days between `05/02/2016` and `25/01/2016` and so on.

Comment: Yes it can be done. You can try analytical functions such as LEAD and LAG to calculate it. BTW plz show what u have tried so far.?

Comment: Can't you add the expected result too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using window functions:

```
select date_column, 
       lag(date_column) over (order by date_column) - date_column as days
from the_table
order by date_column;
```

`lag()` returns the value of the column from the previous row based on the sort order defined in the `order by` part.

In Oracle `date - date` returns the number of days